# Downloading text file only client side

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I could not find how can I "generate" a file and download it only on client side?
For example when the user type some text in the website, I want to give him the option to download it without using a server.

Answer (score -1):

If you are talking about browser javascript, you can not write data directly to local file for security reasons. u can only read

Comment: This is not true. The user has to _allow_ the access.